# Using EF Core FromSql() for Full Text index search on DbSet<Entity> with ValueObject on same table should be without LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2 **.FromSql()** method to run a **full text search** query using CONTAINS() predicate.

**I want to search on all full text indexed columns.**

According to documentation ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), to perform full text search query you can specify:

- column_name
- ( column_list )
- " * " *(query searches all full-text indexed columns)*

There is a method '*EF.Functions.Contains()*' but in only allows to input a single *propertyReference*:

```cs
Expression<Func<T, bool>> searchPredicate = x =>
     EF.Functions.Contains(EF.Property<string>(x, "FirstName"), searchKeyword);
```

I can construct a query using **OR** statement like this:

```cs
Expression<Func<T, bool>> searchPredicate = x =>
     EF.Functions.Contains(EF.Property<string>(x, "FirstName"), searchKeyword) ||
     EF.Functions.Contains(EF.Property<string>(x, "LastName"), searchKeyword);
```

But looking into profiler it constructs the following query which is **undesired**:

```sql
SELECT [x].[Id],
       [x].[FirstName],
       [x].[LastName],
       [x].[Address]
FROM   [Users] AS [x]
WHERE  (CONTAINS([x].[FirstName], 'John' /* @__searchKeyword_1 */))
        OR (CONTAINS([x].[LastName], 'John' /* @__searchKeyword_1 */))
```

So, I should use a custom query in *.FromSql()* to perform a search on all full text indexed columns like this:

```cs
var customQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(*, '\"John\"')";
var users = context.Users.FromSql(customQuery);
```

**Expected query:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(*, '\"John\"');
```

**Actual query:**

```sql
SELECT [p].[Id],
       [p].[FirstName],
       [p].[LastName],
       [p.Address].[Id],
       [p.Address].[Street],
       [p.Address].[StreetNumber]
FROM   (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(*, '\"John\"')) AS [p]
       LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [p.Address]
         ON [p].[Id] = [p.Address].[Id]
```

Entity, ValueObject and OnModelCreating() looks like this:

```cs
public class User : IEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address: IValueObject
{
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().OwnsOne(e => e.Address);
}
```

I am saving Address ValueObject on the same Users table with *.OwnsOne()*.

Using *.FromSql()* on a different entity which doesn't have ValueObject in it works OK and doesn't include LEFT JOIN in the query.

### What should I do to omit LEFT JOIN in the query and perform full text index search correctly?

Comment: Registered an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18616